The best answer of the question doesn’t show in the full newsletter for the “Greatest hits from previous weeks” section
The screenshot below is from English Language Learners Stack Exchange Newsletter - Friday, September 13, 2024, after I clicked the “View entire message” on the email message.



I found this question from the “Greatest hits from previous weeks” section was asked by a user2758804, but the weird thing is the newsletter doesn’t show the user who answered the question. There’s an answer for the question, with a score of 12.
Also happened in the Mathematics Stack Exchange Newsletter - Tuesday, September 3, 2024 “Greatest hits from previous weeks” section (link):



Can this bug be fixed?
I also found it weird, is “Greatest hits from previous weeks” section also includes questions that are from a few years ago? I just used the newsletter since last week.

The Q&A from ELL is from '13. What's that doing in a newsletter from '24 anyway?

@Mast Weird, another example shown in the Mathematics Stack Exchange is a also from ‘24 newsletter.
